# ImageView interpolation while animating

Tags: android, animation, imageview, filtering

I am rotating an *imageview* using a *RotateAnimation*, but the rotation is quite slow (22° in two seconds!).

The image quality during the animation is very *pixelated* from what appears to be a nearest neighbor interpolation.

*Is there any way to change this?*

I've tried `setAntiAlias(true)` on the `BitmapDrawable` with no effect.